# how to display images saved in database with laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

i'm working on a php project and i'm using the laravel framework at version 8. i normally save my images in the database, but the problem is that i can't display my images in my views.
I would like someone to help me, I have already done 3 days under.
Nb: I made a php artisan storage: link

the content of my filesystems.php file

```
<?php

return [


'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Filesystem Disks
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may configure as many filesystem "disks" as you wish, and you
| may even configure multiple disks of the same driver. Defaults have
| been setup for each driver as an example of the required options.
|
| Supported Drivers: "local", "ftp", "sftp", "s3"
|
*/

'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
        'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
        'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
    ],

],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Symbolic Links
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may configure the symbolic links that will be created when the
| `storage:link` Artisan command is executed. The array keys should be
| the locations of the links and the values should be their targets.
|
*/

'links' => [
    public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
],

];
```

my blade view

```
 <div class="row match-height">
                    @foreach($services as $service)
                    <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                            <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-content">
                                <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{{ Storage::disk('public')->url('services/'.$service->image) }}" alt="{{ $service->title }}">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5>{{ $service->title }}</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text  mb-0">{{\Illuminate\Support\Str::limit($service->description, '100')}}</p>
                                    <div class="card-btns d-flex justify-content-between mt-2">
                                        <a href="{{ route('admin.service.edit', $service->id) }}" class="btn gradient-light-primary text-white">Edit</a>
                                        <a href="{{ route('admin.service.show',$service->id) }}" class="btn bg-gradient-info text-white">Show</a>
                                        <button  class="btn btn-outline-danger" type="button" onclick="deleteService({{ $service->id }})">{!! trans('validation.delete') !!}
                                        </button>
                                        <form id="delete-form-{{ $service->id }}" action="{{ route('admin.service.destroy',$service->id) }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                            @csrf
                                            @method('DELETE')
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Profile Cards Ends -->
                    @endforeach
                </div>
```

the code of my controller for the registration of a service:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'category' => 'required',
        'title' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'image' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,bmp,png',

    ]);
    $image = $request->file('image');
    $slug = Str::slug ($request->title);
    if (isset($image))
    {
        $currentDate = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
        $imagename = $slug.'-'.$currentDate.'-'.uniqid('', true).'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        if (!Storage::disk('public')->exists('services'))
        {
            Storage::disk('public')->makeDirectory('services');
        }
        $Imageservice = Image::make($image)->resize(1600,479)->stream();
        Storage::disk('public')->put('services/'.$imagename,$Imageservice);


    } else {
        $imagename = "default.png";
    }
    $service = new Service();
    $service->category_id = $request->category;
    $service->title = $request->title;
    $service->slug = $slug;
    $service->description = $request->description;
    $service->image = $imagename;
    $service->save();

    Toastr::success('Service Successfully Saved :)','Success');
    return redirect()->route('admin.service.create');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you dont have any problem with storing the data and storage is linked with public path properly, you can write something like this to get the image from storage..

```
<img src="{{ url('storage/services/'.$service->image) }}" alt=""/>
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all to access img or any file from storage, you have link storage with public folder...

```
php artisan storage:link
```

using above command it will create shortcut of storage in public folder.

then for display images you can using as like below

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/services'.$service->image) }}" alt="" />
```